# Progress Bar - Only displays for a few Seconds

Tags: android

Playing with an app that when the Camera light in on, it displays the Battery Status. It works fine, but only displays the progress bar for only a few seconds, then shows the bar empty. The text value of the battery status is correct all the time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static Camera cam = null

public int ison = 0;
MediaPlayer click;
private ProgressBar pg;
private TextView batInfo;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
configureImageButton();
click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
pg = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pBar);
pg.setMax(100);
batInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.batInfo);
this.registerReceiver(this.batteryinfoReceiver, new  IntentFilter   (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryinfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        batInfo.setText("%"+level);
         final float[] roundedCorners = new float [] {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};
            ShapeDrawable pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners,null,null));
            String MyColor = level>10?(level<=30?"#ffc800":"#00ff00"):"#ff0000";
            pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
            ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable,Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
            pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);
            pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
            pg.setProgress(level);

    }

};
```